# Connecting local HTML files to Sharepoint database

Tags: javascript, html, database, ms-access, sharepoint

I am new to using this stuff. I need to make some sort of a connection from a local html file on my computer to either Sharepoint or an Access database. I want to be able to pull data from the Sharepoint/Access db and display it on my html page. I also would like to use javascript to accept user input and in turn query those databases with that.

I currently have built some simple vba that outputs an HTML file with table data and another HTML file which houses that table with an iframe on the page. This is very limited and does not provide full functionality. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Is this even possible without those pages being hosted on a server somewhere? I understand I may need to use PHP, but I do not believe I can use that functionality without having these files on a server.

Forgive me if I do not sound like I know what I'm talking about...I don't really :)

Thanks!

Comment: For someone that is new to this, this will be a huge undertaking. You need to understand the SharePoint Client Object Model to be able to do this. A solid understanding of SharePoint architecture will be needed.

Comment: I see. But it is possible to do this with local pages, then? Or is php and server hosting required?

Comment: PHP isn't required, but (of course) SharePoint is. SharePoint is a very sophisticated server-side hardware and software environment. Your page doesn't have to be hosted, but you need to know how to program against it.

Comment: Ok, I will do some more research to familiarize myself with the foundations before I try to take this on. Thank you very much for your help!